# Is there a word for a person who effectively manages multiple tasks over a long period of time?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who effectively manages multiple tasks over a long period of time?

For instance, when you manage your finances, your family, your goals, etc.

Comment: Like... an adult?

Answer (score 1):

Such a person can be called a *multitasker*:

> a person who can perform or manage many tasks at the same time
>   // *The ultimate multitasker, he routinely had a half-dozen or more projects under contract at the same time, all of which would be seen to timely completion.
>
>   — Mark S. Micale*

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multitasker))</sub>

It can be used both for how a person performs within a specific company or organization, but also in the context you mention: a person's entire life.